# How to fill a three dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I want to fill a three dimensional array with the following arrays:

```
double[] y11 = new double[7] { 24, 13.3, 12.2, 14, 22.2, 16.1, 27.9 };
double[] y12 = new double[7] { 3.5, 3.5, 4, 4, 3.6, 4.3, 5.2 };

double[] y21 = new double[7] { 7.4, 13.2, 8.5, 10.1, 9.3, 8.5, 4.3 };
double[] y22 = new double[7] { 3.5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2.5, 1.5 };

double[] y31 = new double[5] { 16.4, 24, 53, 32.7, 42.8 };
double[] y32 = new double[5] { 3.2, 2.5, 1.5, 2.6, 2 };

double[] y41 = new double[2] { 25.1, 5.9 };
double[] y42 = new double[2] { 2.7, 2.3 };
```

for instance **y12** means the array in group 1 , column number 2 and so on. so i have 4 groups ,each group has 2 columns.

```
public class Matrix
{
    double[, ,] matrix;
    public void Initial(int groupSize, int columnSize, int valueSize)
    {
        matrix = new double[groupSize, columnSize, valueSize];
    }
}
```

I need a simple flexible Add method for the matrix, rather than assigning each value like `matrix[1][2][3] = value;`

I've tried this, but couldn't get it work

```
public void Add(double[] columnArray, int groupIndex, int columnIndex)
{
    matrix[i, y] = columnArray;
}
```

Comment: If you make it `double[,][] matrix;` you can use a single assignment but that's a shallow copy. The different sizes seem to require this too.

Comment: @HenkHolterman im confused which one to which, `[groupSize][columnSize, valueSize]` like that?

Comment: [group, column][valueIndex]

Comment: guys please can someone provide me with a proper answer, im still getting error on `matrix = new double[groupSize, columnSize][valueSize];` : `Invalid rank specifier: expected ',' or ']'`

Comment: It's `double[groupSize, columnSize][]` or maybe `double[][groupSize, columnSize]`. You can't set it in 1 go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to @Henk Holterman 's Comment (thank you), I've managed to solve the problem

```
public class Matrix
{
    double[,][] matrix;
    public Matrix(int groupSize, int columnSize)
    {
        matrix = new double[groupSize, columnSize][];
    }
    public void Add(double[] arr, int groupIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        matrix[groupIndex, columnIndex] = arr;
    }
    public void Print()
    {
        int columnIndex = 0;
        int groupIndex = 0;
        int groupSize = matrix.GetLength(0);
        int columnSize = matrix.GetLength(1);
        while (groupIndex < groupSize)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < matrix[groupIndex, columnIndex].Length; k++)
            {
                Console.Write(groupIndex + 1);
                while (columnIndex < columnSize)
                {
                    Console.Write("        {0}", matrix[groupIndex, columnIndex][k]);
                    columnIndex++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                columnIndex = 0;
            }
            groupIndex++;
        }
    }

}
```

Main Class

```
    static Matrix m;
    static void SetDataSet()
    {
        double[] y11 = new double[7] { 24, 13.3, 12.2, 14, 22.2, 16.1, 27.9 };
        double[] y12 = new double[7] { 3.5, 3.5, 4, 4, 3.6, 4.3, 5.2 };

        double[] y21 = new double[7] { 7.4, 13.2, 8.5, 10.1, 9.3, 8.5, 4.3 };
        double[] y22 = new double[7] { 3.5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2.5, 1.5 };

        double[] y31 = new double[5] { 16.4, 24, 53, 32.7, 42.8 };
        double[] y32 = new double[5] { 3.2, 2.5, 1.5, 2.6, 2 };

        double[] y41 = new double[2] { 25.1, 5.9 };
        double[] y42 = new double[2] { 2.7, 2.3 };

        m.Add(y11, 0, 0);
        m.Add(y12, 0, 1);
        m.Add(y21, 1, 0);
        m.Add(y22, 1, 1);
        m.Add(y31, 2, 0);
        m.Add(y32, 2, 1);
        m.Add(y41, 3, 0);
        m.Add(y42, 3, 1);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        m = new Matrix(4,2);
        SetDataSet();
        m.Print();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

[image]