# how to multiply a given Matrix by its transpose?

Tags: c#, matrix, transpose

I have to create a method to multiply a given Matrix by its transpose.

[image]

Consider my matrix is 2d array `double [][] matrix;`

```
public double[][] MultiplyByTranspose(double[][] matrix) 
{  
    return newMatrix;
}
```

If you need my Matrix class check it in the [answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014303/how-to-fill-a-three-dimensional-array)

Comment: @Octoshape what can i try if i don't know how to rotate the matrix! if you can't help, stop posting the same old useless comment

Comment: excuse me for trying to accommodate to this site's rules, but it doesn't seem like you have tried anything (hence probably the downvote, which isn't mine by the way).

Comment: You don't have to rotate the matrix at all, rotation is just a simple tool to visualize what transposing a matrix looks like. When you transpose a matrix you treat the columns as rows and the rows as columns, i.e. the first row becomes the first column and so on.

Comment: @Dirk that's true .. I'm working on it right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the simplest way is just to *implement* Transpose and Multiplication.

Of course, when *combined*, it could be done *more efficient*, but I think that you'll need Transpose and Multiplication as *separated routine* further in your code (you've asked about matrix *rotation*)

```
public static Boolean IsRectangle(Double[][] value) {
  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, value))
    return false;
  else if (value.Length <= 0)
    return false;

  Double[] line = value[value.Length - 1];

  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, line))
    return false;

  int size = line.Length;

  for (int i = value.Length - 2; i >= 0; --i)
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, value[i]))
      return false;
    else if (value[i].Length != size)
      return false;

  return true;
}

public static Double[][] Transpose(Double[][] value) {
  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, value))
    throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

  if (!IsRectangle(value))
    throw new ArgumentException("value should be a rectangular matrix.", "value");

  int colCount = value.Length;
  int rowCount = value[value.Length - 1].Length;

  Double[][] result = new Double[rowCount][];

  for (int i = rowCount - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    Double[] line = new Double[colCount];
    result[i] = line;

    for (int j = colCount - 1; j >= 0; --j)
      line[j] = value[j][i];
  }

  return result;
}

// Simple quibic algorithm
public static Double[][] Multiply(Double[][] left, Double[][] right) {
  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, left))
    throw new ArgumentNullException("left");
  else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, right))
    throw new ArgumentNullException("right");

  if (!IsRectangle(left))
    throw new ArgumentException("left should be a rectangular matrix", "left");
  else if (!IsRectangle(right))
    throw new ArgumentException("right should be a rectangular matrix", "right");

  int leftRows = left.Length;
  int leftCols = left[0].Length;

  int rightRows = right.Length;
  int rightCols = right[0].Length;

  if (leftCols != rightRows)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("right");

  Double[][] result = new Double[leftRows][];

  for (int r = leftRows - 1; r >= 0; --r) {
    Double[] leftLine = left[r];
    Double[] line = new Double[rightCols];
    result[r] = line;

    for (int c = rightCols - 1; c >= 0; --c) {
      Double s = 0.0;

      for (int i = leftCols - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        s += leftLine[i] * right[i][c];

      line[c] = s;
    }
  }

  return result;
}

...

public double[][] MultiplyByTranspose(double[][] matrix) {  
  //TODO: Check the order! Which matrix should be the first and which the second,
  // In Linear Algebra A * B != B * A 
  return Multiply(matrix, Transpose(matrix));
  // Or 
  // return Multiply(Transpose(matrix), matrix);
}
```

Comment: why does it only work on rectangular matrices? might be a dumb question, but just wondering..

Comment: @Octoshape: As far as I know, linear algebra (Transpose, Multiplication etc.) uses rectangle matrixes only, not jagged ones.

Comment: @Octoshape Mathematically there are only rectangular matrices, with square matrices as a special case. However using `double[][]` to describe a matrix does not guarantee that it's rectangular. For that you'd have to use a `double[,]`.

Comment: Wouldn't "transposing" the indexes actually be easier than doing a real transpose?

Comment: @harold: Yes, you're quite right: the simplest (and fastest) solution is to eliminate Transpose and slightly modify Multiply (just swap indexes/loops). I've put them as separate methods because author asked about matrix's routation in a comment.

Comment: I just noticed that the input have to be `double[]` not `double[][]` according to MANOVA steps, i will pass 2x1 matrix, can i still use your code as it is, or should i change it? ofcourse the result of multiplication remains `double[][]`

Comment: Matrix multiplication requires matrixes, so left as well as right should be Double[][]. Moreover, there are two possibilities for vector (that is Double[]): column or line vector which are Double[2][1] and Double[1][2] correspondingly. In case of 2x1 matrix (two lines of one item each) Double[][] v = new Double[] {new Double[] {a11}, new Double[] {a21}};